# CSS - divs in the middle of the screen on mobile device

Tags: html, css

What I have:

***CODEPEN***: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKKxdL

[image: A]

What I need:

[image: B]

I tried

```
.days {
    ...
    overflow: auto;
    ...
}

.flex {
    ...

    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    position: relative;

    ...
}
```

But items was in the middl, but I cant scroll to left (scroll bar isnt in the middle)

Comment: Why not make it responsive with .flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

Comment: @cwattsdis Because I do not want it? OMG

Comment: @Altaula Did you delete this question then reposted it? I assume that my answer wasn't what your looking for. You could've just updated the original post instead wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the min-width property.  If the screen is narrower than your min-width, a horizontal scroll bar should be added.